# Terraform for AWS: How to (and can I safely) ignore an error related to scaling down the Batch Compute Environment?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I often see errors like this when updating a configuration with `terraform apply`:

```
Error: error updating Batch Compute Environment (dev-james-data-ingest): Manually scaling down compute environment is not supported.  Disconnecting job queues from compute environment will cause it to scale-down to minvCpus.
    status code: 400, request id: ed1a562b-dfc8-4e3f-af9b-e3efba4dbfe7
```

My experience has been that this seems to be an innocuous error that can be safely ignored. (But is this actually the case?)

I'm writing a Python script that wraps Terraform commands, calling the `terraform` executable via the [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module. Under the above assumption about the harmlessness of this error, I catch the exception raised by the call to `sh.terraform` and if the `stderr` contains the known error message related to this error then I swallow it, otherwise, I raise the exception:

```
    try:
        sh.terraform("apply", "-auto-approve", plan_file)
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode as err_code:
        if (
            "Manually scaling down compute environment is not supported.  "
            "Disconnecting job queues from compute environment will cause it to scale-down to minvCpus."
            not in str(err_code.stderr)
        ):
            raise
```

Am I detecting this error correctly or is there a way to capture more specific info from Terraform and use that to determine if the issue is the compute environment scale down issue or not? Or is this compute environment scale down problem really a bonafide error and the `terraform apply` command should be considered in error overall?

Comment: did you get anser?